# how to show alert confirmaton on click of delete button

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Please look at the following example,

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file)

Please look at the example in stackblitz, I can drag and upload images there. Once i will drag and upload the image, delete button will appear. How can I write click function for that delete button in angular 2 and how to get the droped file url?

If i click that delete button it should ask the confirmation, "Are you sure you want to delete?"

I can't able to find way how to write onclick function for that delete button? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I can't see any code you have written on it for upload. check if you posted a correct saved one. One suggestion is to use `@HostListener()` decorator to add events.

Comment: Its correct code only. Delete function will happen. Please check once. Delete code is there somewhere inside dependencies. I didn't write any code, its plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `deleteFile` EventEmiter

Html:

```
<input-file (deletedFile)="confirmDelete()" inputId="input-file" placeholder="Drop files below!"></input-file>
        </div>
```

JS:-

```
confirmDelete() {
    var result = confirm("Want to delete?");
if (result) {        
    alert('Deleted');
} else {
  alert('Not deleted');
}
  }
```

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file-rr2lvr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: So, when you cancel it what happens? @sathishkumar

Comment: How to get the uploaded file name or image url after drop the image in a field

Answer (score 0):

You can use sweetalerts for that here is the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2

wait i will implement & share you the stackblitz link in a while

Comment: please help me. I want to write on click function. If i got the click function , i will resolve 3 more defects.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the documentation. The component supported `deletedFile` to trigger when you delete the figures.

**html**

```
<input-file inputId="input-file" placeholder="Drop files below!" (deletedFile)="deleteG()"></input-file>
```

**appcomponent.ts**

```
export class AppComponent { 

  deleteG(){
    console.log('here you detect the delete when you click delete icon');
  }
}
```